# How to create an Akka Stream Source that generates items recursively

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I'm trying to figure out how to create an Akka Streams source that generates many Seq[Int].

Basically, given an int `n` I want to generate all of the `Seq[Int]` of 1 to n

Here's some code that does this:

```
def combinations(n: Int): Seq[Seq[Int]] = {
    def loop(acc: (Seq[Int], Seq[Seq[Int]]),
             remaining: Seq[Int]): Seq[Seq[Int]] = {
      remaining match {
        case s if s.size == 1 => {
          val total: Seq[Seq[Int]] = acc._2
          val current: Seq[Int] = acc._1
          total :+ (current :+ s.head)
        }
        case _ => {
          for {
            x <- remaining
            comb <- loop((acc._1 :+ x, acc._2), remaining.filter(_ != x))
          } yield comb
        }
      }
    }

    loop((Seq(), Seq()), (1 to n))
  }
```

This works fine up to 10... then it blows up because it runs out of memory. Since I just want to process each of them and don't need to keep them all in memory, I thought... Akka Streams. But I'm at a loss for how to turn this into a Source that produces each combination so I can process them. Basically there where it's appending to total I would produce another item onto the stream.

Comment: I upvoted your question because it is interesting. However, I'm not sure you need Akka Streams. The normal Streams implementation should be enough to implement this. Although your question didn't ask this, I am wondering how to make your code tail call optimized, so that it will work without danger of stack overflow.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering that too, but it didn't seem as pressing as not running out of memory ;)

Comment: I would suggest editing your question to include the "scala" tag. That way, other people may find it.

Comment: Anyway, I will think about your question. It is interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses the Johnson-Trotter algorithm for permutations. `tcopermutations` creates a LazyList that can be evaluated as needed. For more permutations, just pass a different value to `printNIterations`.

The reason for using the Johnson-Trotter algorithm is that it breaks the recursive structure of the permutation finding algorithm. That's important for being able to evaluate successive instances of the permutation and storing them in some kind of lazy list or stream.

```
object PermutationsTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    printNIterations(50, tcopermutations(5).iterator)
  }

  def printNIterations(n: Int, it: Iterator[Seq[Int]]): Unit = {
    if (n<=0) ()
    else {
      if (it.hasNext) {
        println(it.next())
        printNIterations(n - 1, it)
      } else ()
    }

  }

  def naivepermutations(n: Int): Seq[Seq[Int]] = {
    def loop(acc: Seq[Int], remaining: Seq[Int]): Seq[Seq[Int]] = {
      remaining match {
        case s if s.size == 1 => {
          val current: Seq[Int] = acc
          Seq((current :+ s.head))
        }
        case _ => {
          for {
            x <- remaining
            comb <- loop(acc :+ x, remaining.filter(_ != x))
          } yield comb
        }
      }
    }

    loop(Seq(), (1 to n))
  }

  def tcopermutations(n: Int): LazyList[Seq[Int]] = {
    val start = (1 to n).map(Element(_, Left))

    def loop(v: Seq[Element]): LazyList[Seq[Element]] = {
      johnsonTrotter(v) match {
        case Some(s) => v #:: loop(s)
        case None => LazyList(v)
      }
    }
    loop(start).map(_.map(_.i))
  }

  def checkIfMobile(seq: Seq[Element], i: Int): Boolean = {
    val e = seq(i)

    def getAdjacent(s: Seq[Element], d: Direction, j: Int): Int = {
      val adjacentIndex = d match {
        case Left => j - 1
        case Right => j + 1
      }
      s(adjacentIndex).i
    }

    if (e.direction == Left && i == 0) false
    else if (e.direction == Right && i == seq.size - 1) false
    else if (getAdjacent(seq, e.direction, i) < e.i) true
    else false
  }

  def findLargestMobile(seq: Seq[Element]): Option[Int] = {
    val mobiles = (0 until seq.size).filter{j => checkIfMobile(seq, j)}
    if (mobiles.isEmpty) None
    else {
      val folded = mobiles.map(x=>(x,seq(x).i)).foldLeft(None: Option[(Int, Int)]){ case (acc, elem) =>
        acc match {
          case None => Some(elem)
          case Some((i, value)) => if (value > elem._2) Some((i, value)) else Some(elem)
        }
      }
      folded.map(_._1)
    }
  }

  def swapLargestMobile(seq: Seq[Element], index: Int): (Seq[Element], Int) = {
    val dir = seq(index).direction
    val value = seq(index).i
    dir match {
      case Right =>
        val folded = seq.foldLeft((None, Seq()): (Option[Element], Seq[Element])){(acc, elem) =>
          val matched = elem.i == value
          val newAccOpt = if (matched) Some(elem) else None
          val newAccSeq = acc._1 match {
            case Some(swapMe) => acc._2 :+ elem :+ swapMe
            case None => if (matched) acc._2 else acc._2 :+ elem
          }
          (newAccOpt, newAccSeq)
        }
        (folded._2, index + 1)
      case Left =>
        val folded = seq.foldRight((None, Seq()): (Option[Element], Seq[Element])){(elem, acc) =>
          val matched = elem.i == value
          val newAccOpt = if (matched) Some(elem) else None
          val newAccSeq = acc._1 match {
            case Some(swapMe) => swapMe +: elem +: acc._2
            case None => if (matched) acc._2 else elem +: acc._2
          }
          (newAccOpt, newAccSeq)
        }
        (folded._2, index - 1)
    }
  }

  def revDirLargerThanMobile(seq: Seq[Element], mobile: Int) = {
    def reverse(e: Element) = {
      e.direction match {
        case Left => Element(e.i, Right)
        case Right => Element(e.i, Left)
      }
    }
    seq.map{ elem =>
      if (elem.i > seq(mobile).i) reverse(elem)
      else elem
    }
  }

  def johnsonTrotter(curr: Seq[Element]): Option[Seq[Element]] = {
    findLargestMobile(curr).map { m =>
      val (swapped, newMobile) = swapLargestMobile(curr, m)
      revDirLargerThanMobile(swapped, newMobile)
    }
  }

  trait Direction
  case object Left extends Direction
  case object Right extends Direction

  case class Element(i: Int, direction: Direction)
}
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks! Since I wanted to still try this out with Akka Streams I was able to just do Source.fromIterator(() => tcopermutations(12).iterator) and it worked perfectly!